# e2fsck aftercare

Tags: e2fsck

I had filesystem errors on `/home`, an ext4 partition. I was able to reboot into recovery mode and run `e2fsck`, which found and fixed a long list of errors. (Later I found that periodic checking was disabled.) After that, I was able to reboot to the desktop, and everything *appears* to be fine.

Now I'm wondering: How do I assess the damage (if any)? I checked in `/home/lost+found` and it is empty; that's encouraging. But is there anything else I could or should do to find out whether data was lost?

In case it matters, I'm on Debian stable 10.7.

Comment: I take it that you didn't save the output from fsck with the list of detected errors and performed fixes, did you?

Comment: @TooTea unfortunately not. And I couldn't find a log of it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a fresh backup to compare with, there's nothing you can do.

In rare cases e2fsck truncates files to zero - you might look for them.

Answer (score 1):

On old Unix, `lost+found` was (I think) used for any orphaned file.  In `e2fsck`, I believe it is only used for orphaned directories.  `e2fsck` also only ever seems to have one fix for an error.

In any case, you should also:

1. Use `tune2fs` to turn on periodic checking on your existing filesystems.
2. Edit `/etc/mke2fs.conf` to make the default be to include periodic checking.